# What would be the equivalent to SetForegroundWindow with X11?

Tags: c++, window, x11

I'm part of the [SFML Team](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) and we're currently looking into a feature to "request" window focus. The goal is to get very similar behavior across Windows, OS X and Linux.

For Windows one gets the rather simple [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function via the WinAPI, which has a few condition as to how the window actually gets focus. The most important part to notice here is, that it only gets focus if it's from the same foreground process.

On OS X it's possible to get the focus for the active app only and otherwise let the icon bounce, i.e. notification.

Here comes the problem now, we'd like to get the same behavior on Linux as well, meaning the window should get focus if the window belongs to the active/foreground process and otherwise it should generate a notification. What would be the closest thing to that with X11?

There are already a [few suggestions](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/pull/613) on the issue tracker of SFML, but none of them are actually implementing this behavior.

**"User Story"**

I guess developers can think of different things when being confronted with different technical names, as such here's the issue from a user perspective.

There are mainly two situations in which requesting focus is needed:

- Sometimes when starting an application that uses a console window in the background, it *can* happen that the console window gets the focus instead of the actual GUI window. When this happens it's rather annoying for the user having to click on the window first. Since the console window and the GUI window are from the same application there's no harm done in switching the focus to the GUI window.
- When one is writing an application that supports multiple windows, there might be situations where the application should decide which window gets the focus and again since the window belong to the same application there's no harm done in switching the focus from one GUI window to the other GUI window.
- Further more if a different application has the focus/is being used then it's not okay to steal the focus and as such we just want to get the user's attention. For Windows that might be a blinking taskbar or for OS X that might be a jumping icon.

The current implementation seems to work fine on OS X and Windows, butwe're unsure about the X11 implementation. Thus the question is: How would one go about switching the window focus if the currently focussed window has been created by the same application that makes the focus request and otherwise create some kind of notification. For the notification we're/I'm not even sure if there's some generic way of doing it with X11.

Comment: (1) There is no such thing as an active/foreground process on Linux. (2) Windows belong not to processes, but to *clients* (which may be processes on any computer on the network, or hardware devices). The whole thing is very poorly defined. What behaviour do you actually need? Tell a **user story**. Users have no idea what words like "process" or "focus" or "foreground" mean.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. for your comment. I've added some more info that hopefully explain things a bit better.

Comment: How have you done this in Mac?

Comment: You can find the full implementation for SFML on GitHub: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/src/SFML/Window/OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In X11, "focus" means "the keyboard focus", that is, the window that gets the keyboard input. The window that has the focus is not necessarily in the foreground. This depends on your window manager focus policy. Most can be configured to have "click-to-focus" or "point-to-focus" policy. If you are interested in the keyboard focus, use `XSetInputFocus`. If you want to bring your window to the foreground, use `XRaiseWindow`.

It is OK to call `RaiseWindow` and `XSetInputFocus` once, when the application starts. It is also OK to bring a window to the foreground/set focus as a response to a user interaction with that or some other window of the same application. But it's not OK to do so as a response to some background event (time passed, file downloaded etc).

The standard X11 method of drawing attention to a window is setting the urgency hint. This will normally flash or bounce the icon, depending on your window manager. Do not forget to unset the hint when the user finally interacts with the window.

I think all of this has been discussed in the thread you have linked. I'm not quite sure which concerns are still left unanswered. Nothing can implement the exact same behaviour as with the other windowing systems, simply because X11 is not those windowing systems, and it's totally OK. X11, Mac OS X and Windows all behave differently and the users know and expect that. It would annoy me to no end if some application on X11 decided to behave exactly like it does on Windows, instead of toeing the X11 party line.

Comment: Thanks! The main reason I opened this question here, was because I wanted to get some second opinion on things, especially from someone that has been doing quite a bit of X11 development. I don't know how much the other participants know about X11 deevelopment, but it seemed like there were quite a few uncertainties.